# flash.net.Socket "complete event"

Tags: apache-flex

Is there any way to know if data is completely received on the other end of a flash.net.Socket? Like a complete event? Based on the event documentation there is none. If there is no way, what are the alternative strategies?

Answer (score 0):

The beauty of Flash is that you don't need to.  Flash handles it for you after it's sent.  It gets queued, sent over the wire and awaits confirmation (as per the protocol).  If there's a problem, an error event will be dispatched and the fault object will have the specifics of the error.

If there's a problem in the transmission (like disconnection, bad route, etc), it will retry 3 times I believe in a span of 30 seconds (timeout).  I believe these numbers can be changed, but I wouldn't if I were you.  They're pretty much the most optimal in my experience.

Comment: Thnx, but I need to be notified of its completion so that i will proceed to the next. If I flood the socket with data, on the other end, the files are not completely sent... :)

Comment: http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/flexcoders/messages/72018?threaded=1&m=e&var=1&tidx=1 - something I read.

Comment: Again, you don't have to care about it.  You can't flood the socket unless the server can't handle the data, which I doubt unless you're on fiber-op and sending *a lot* of data.  I mean gigs upon gigs every second.  You don't need to wait for it, just flush.  It'll work.